# c array error, skips some elements

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, skip

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{

  int length,i,j;

  char *key;

  printf("\n\n\n   What is the length of key?\n");
  scanf("%d",&length);

  key=(char*)malloc (length*sizeof(char));

  for(i=0;i<length;i++)
  {
                      printf("\n Enter  %d. character ...\n",i+1);
                      scanf("%c",&key[i]);
 }

 getch();
  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```

When i execute, it asks

enter 1.character
enter 2. character
inputhere
enter 3.char
enter 4.char

It goes like that, it doesnot ask odd ones.Not only odd ones, if for example length is 7, it asks 4 and then 3 characters. Why can this be?

Comment: You may be surprised if you try checking the *value* in the `key[i]` as well as the return value of that scanf call for slots that are seemingly skipped. When doing so, think about everything (*everything*) you're entering on your keyboard during that loop.

Comment: i made printf before this loop to see if scanf is wrong but still it printed stupid things.

Comment: And when you enter your keyboard input, what *exactly* are you entering. *Every keystroke*. If it helps at all consider this: the `%c` format specifier for `scanf` does *not* skip whitespace. Hmm... Think about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%c` conversion specifier won't skip over leading whitespace characters, so it's picking the newline character that's still in the input stream from the previous entry.  IOW, suppose you type in a length of 10.  The input stream then contains the characters '1'. '0', and '\n'.  The first `scanf("%d", &length)` call consumes the '1' and the '0', but leaves the '\n' in the input stream.  Thus, the first `scanf("%c", &key[i])` reads the '\n' character, not the character you entered.

The workaround for this is to add a blank space in the format string before the `%c` conversion specifier: `scanf(" %c", &key[i])`.  This will tell `scanf` to skip over any learning whitespace and read the first non-whitespace character into `key[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is %c considers enter key also as input

once you allocate the memory instead of reading char by char, just read it as string using  scanf("%s", key), or if you still want to read char by char change %d instead of %c in your scanf statement which will work, only %c to %d nothing else